# Only local connections are allowed. Chrome failed to start: crashed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, build-automation

I am running Selenium Automation Script From Jenkins+Git+Maven. in local machine, the script working absolutely  Perfect but when I run this from Jenkins it gives me below error.

OS Linux 
chrome driver  version 83.0.4103.39
chrome version 83.0.4103.61

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver"); 
            ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
            opt.setBinary("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");  //chrome binary location specified here
            opt.addArguments("start-maximized");
            opt.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
            opt.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

---

### T E S T S

Running com.spicetag.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 15818
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Tests run: 9, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 8, Time elapsed: 2.189 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.spicetag.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest
setup(com.spicetag.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest)  Time elapsed: 2.021 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'
System info: host: 'shankar', ip: '192.168.43.69', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-91-generic', java.version: '11.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x563918a38579

```
at com.spicetag.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.setup(LoginPageTest.java:29)
```

Results :

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change the path

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

To the right path chrome.driver

If it still doesn't work, please paste the error code

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But I am working on Linux

Comment: So your code is wrong, you need to change it